# session.load() not showing sql queries on console

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am  newbie to hibernate, when I query using load method in hibernate, sql queries are not printed on the console. I have also mentioned the entries in my `Hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Entries in `Hibernate.cfg.xml` file :

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">P@ssw0rd@123</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="hibernate/pojo/EmpDataEntity.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate/pojo/EmpDtlsEntity.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate/pojo/TeamEntity.hbm.xml"/>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my Criteria Query is :

```
EmpDtlsEntity empDtlsEntity = (EmpDtlsEntity)session.load(EmpDtlsEntity.class,1);
```

Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

Are you sure your this mapping is right？ I think it lack of the database name

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**databaseName**

Comment: No, there is no problem with the mapping,actually it is working with the session.get but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`session.load` may return proxy, meaning it may not go to database (only id is set in the proxy). The instance will be initialized from the database once you access a property on it.

If you desire to load the instance from database immediately, you can use `session.get`.